# SvelteKit with adapter-static throws an error > 404 at <img> path in markup

Tags: sveltekit

`src` attribute in `img` uses absolute path:

```
<script>
    let herbURL = '/media/events/odessa/gerb.png',
</script>

<img src={thumbURL} />
```

And while `npm run dev` works fine, `npm run build` thwrows en error:

```
> 404 /media/events/odessa/gerb.png (linked from /)
Error: 404
```

But when I move `media` folder in `build`folder — build as well work ok.

The problem is only with paths for `src` attribute in `img` tags: `adapter-static` for some reason couldn't find them (thoug he does see images in `background` url's in css).

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to put assets not into the `root`, but into the `static` folder! So `media` folder for example should be in `static/media`.